# Dynamically serve static content based on server name in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a web application in Django that is accessed from multiple domains to the same IP address. The idea is that each domain the application is accessed from will receive unique branding.

So for example, if there were two domains, reseller.com and oem.com, and you went to oem.com, it would take you to to the same website as reseller.com, but with differently themed content (say, sent from /static/oem.com/{files} instead of /static/reseller.com/{files}).

Basically my idea has been to define a custom template tag, that receives the SERVER_NAME as an argument, which would return the location of the content.

Are there any alternatives, or simply easier options?

Edit: I should probably add that I'm using MongoDB for this project, and as such it's more than likely Django's ORM won't be used for the project.

Edit again: More clarification; I'm using nginx.

Comment: can you rewrite your static URLs based on referrer HTTP header?

Comment: Could you elaborate? I've checked request.META for the base url and of course no HTTP_REFERER is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to do simple rewrite rule in nginx. Aside from a template tag (if you are only swapping out static content, then I think a template tag is the way to go), if the sites are gonna be different at all, template-wise, you can handle it by writing a custom template loader.

This allows you to pick what templates you would like to use when you render your page. This method has a graceful way of failing if the loader fails to find a matching template for your specific domain. If it doesn't find a match, it will fall back to your main templates directory. So you could have custom stuff for some domains, and more generic for others.

But to make a decision what to serve based upon a request header, you'll need to make the request available to the loader via _thread_locals, I do this in some middleware:

```
#custom.middleware.py
try:
    from threading import local
except ImportError:
    from django.utils._threading_local import local

_thread_locals = local()

def get_current_request():
    return getattr(_thread_locals, 'request', None)

class RequestMiddleware():
    def process_request(self, request):
        _thread_locals.request = request
```

Next write a template loader (update the path to your middleware):

```
#custom.loaders.py
from os.path import join
from django.conf import settings
from django.template import TemplateDoesNotExist
from path.to.middleware import get_current_request

def load_template_source(template_name, template_dirs=None):
    request = get_current_request()
    host = request.get_host()
    path_to_template_dir = None
    for site in settings.SITE_TEMPLATE_FOLDERS:
        if site[0] == host:
            path_to_template_dir = site[1]
            break

    if path_to_template_dir:
        try:
            filepath = join(path_to_template_dir, template_name)
            file = open(filepath)
            try:
                return (file.read(), filepath)
            finally:
                file.close()
        except IOError:
                pass

    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name)
```

and lastly update your settings file with three things 1) add the template loader (make sure its listed first) 2) add the middleware  3) and then add a new variable SITE_TEMPLATE_FOLDERS with a tuple of tuples containing domains and paths to template folders:

```
#settings.py

.....

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'custom.loaders.load_template_source',
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'domain.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'custom.middleware.RequestMiddleware',
)

SITE_TEMPLATE_FOLDERS = (
    ('mydomain.com', '/path/to/templates'),
    ('myotherdomain.com', '/path/to/other/templates')
)
...
```

Seems like a lot, but now you can easily add a new domain via your settings file.

Comment: This is fantastic! I've gone with a very simple approach, using a ~20 line context manager, but I'm going to discuss this method with the rest of my team.

Comment: but this does not help when static contents are served by a separate dedicated server.

Comment: its a different solution than was asked in the original question, but it provides for some additional rendering flexibility. like i said up front,  if you purely want to swap static content, then this isn't the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [the "sites" framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/).

Comment: Thanks for that Ignacio, but I most likely won't be using Django's ORM due to the fact that I'm using MongoDB for the project.

Comment: I'll leave my answer up regardless though, since other searchers may be fine with it.

Comment: @Nathan Hoad: You can use Django ORM for Sites, Sessions and Authentication and still use MongoDB for other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

For example, Apache has mod_rewrite that you can use to rewrite URLs:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^www.domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule /static/[^/]+ /static/domain1/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^www.domain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule /static/[^/]+ /static/domain2/$1 [L]`

(this is untested)

other servers also have similar functionality.

Just make sure your django application emits static urls that are site-independent and can be correctly rewritten.

Comment: This looks great. I'll look into this and let you know.